# Calculate the average position of a value in an array fast method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got the following code to calculate the **average position of 1s** in a 2D numpy array that contains 1's and 0's. The issue is that it's very slow and I was wondering if a faster method is possible?

```
row_sum = 0
col_sum = 0
ones_count = 0

for row_count, row in enumerate(array):
    for col_count, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == 1:
            row_sum += row_count
            col_sum += col_count
            ones_count += 1

average_position_ones = (row_sum / ones_count, col_sum / ones_count)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to be quicker at calculating `row_sum`, `col_sum` and `ones_count`.

#### Baseline

For testing I use this array

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

np.random.seed(1)

n = 10**4
array = np.random.randint(0,2,(n,n))
```

Now your exact code takes `20.3 s ± 397 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` on my machine.

#### The Lazy One Liner Numpy Version:

`%timeit np.stack(np.where(array)).sum(axis=1),array.sum()` takes `1.13 s ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` on my machine.

Here `np.stack(np.where(array)).sum(axis=1)` is what you call `row_sum` and `col_sum` and `array.sum()` gives your `ones_count`

#### Avoid Looping Threw Twice

You can use your exact code with `numba.jit`

```
@nb.njit
def test():
    row_sum = 0
    col_sum = 0
    ones_count = 0

    for row_count, row in enumerate(array):
        for col_count, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == 1:
                row_sum += row_count
                col_sum += col_count
                ones_count += 1

    return row_sum,col_sum,ones_count

%timeit test()
```

This is a bit faster. It takes  `50 ms ± 614 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` on my machine. But defininitly not worth the effort.

#### Multicore Version

A slight modification of your code can run multithreaded with `numba`

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def test2():
    row_sum = 0
    col_sum = 0
    ones_count = 0
    
    for row_count in nb.prange(len(array)):
        row = array[row_count]
        for col_count, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == 1:
                row_sum += row_count
                col_sum += col_count
                ones_count += 1

    return row_sum,col_sum,ones_count

%timeit test2()
```

Now this does give a little speed up compared to the lazy `numpy` version. It takes `13.3 ms ± 2.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` on my 10 core machine. Though it's not using all 10 cores.

Notice that you have to be careful when modifying things in parallel. You could create a race condition. And this is not the case here only because `numba` takes counter measures for this specific case.

#### Further Optimisations

As pointed out by Jérôme Richard in a comment. The last version can be optimised by using uint8 to sture the  instead of int64 which is the default. Just call `.astype(np.uint8)` on the array. Then it takes `9.38 ms ± 935 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` on my machine.

Comment: Note that using a 32-bit or 64-bit integer array to store a binary digit is a bit inefficient. You can use `np.uint8` so the array can take 4x/8x less memory and thus can be computed faster (especially with many cores as the computation is mostly memory bound). You can do that with `np.random.randint(0,2,(n,n)).astype(np.uint8)`. I hope the OP use 8-bit integers or booleans. (Note that there are some tricks to speed up the code even further in this case but this should be enough for the OP).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I added a paragraph about that to my post.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you can get total sum of the array by `np.sum()` (provided the array contains only 0/1):

```py
ones_count = array.sum()

print((arr.shape[0] - 1) / ones_count, (arr.shape[1] - 1) / ones_count)
```

Comment: I do not think this gives a correct result. `row_count` is not the number of row despite its name.

Comment: @JérômeRichard - Thie solution's result is equal to OP's solution.

Comment: At least before the question was updated.